# Spring mvc application does not start in Tomcat when i add global-method-security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, tomcat7

I am trying add method level security to my Spring MCV/Security. The application works if don't add
`<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>`.

I want method level security on controller methods which have request mappings

Tomcat error

FAIL - Application at context path /commerce could not be started

**This is my folder structure.**

[image]

Here are all my files.

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Declare a view resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
            p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security  -->

    <security:http auto-config="false"
                   use-expressions="true"
                   access-denied-page="/auth/denied"
                   entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" >

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/main/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/main/common" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

        <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
                         logout-success-url="/auth/login"
                         logout-url="/auth/logout"/>

        <security:custom-filter ref="blacklistFilter" before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR"/>
        <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
    </security:http>



    <!--  Custom filter to deny unwanted users even though registered -->
    <bean id="blacklistFilter" class="org.krams.commerce.filter.BlacklistFilter" />

    <!-- Custom filter for username and password. The real customization is done in the customAthenticationManager -->
    <bean id="authenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
        p:authenticationManager-ref="customAuthenticationManager"
        p:authenticationFailureHandler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        p:authenticationSuccessHandler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

    <!-- Custom authentication manager. In order to authenticate, username and password must not be the same -->
    <bean id="customAuthenticationManager" class="org.krams.commerce.manager.CustomAuthenticationManager" />

    <!-- We just actually need to set the default failure url here -->
    <bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        p:defaultFailureUrl="/auth/login?error=true" />

     <!-- We just actually need to set the default target url here -->
    <bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        p:defaultTargetUrl="/main/common" />

    <!-- The AuthenticationEntryPoint is responsible for redirecting the user to a particular page, like a login page,
            whenever the server sends back a response requiring authentication -->
    <!-- See Spring-Security Reference 5.4.1 for more info -->
    <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        p:loginFormUrl="/auth/login"/>

    <!-- The tag below has no use but Spring Security needs it to autowire the parent property of
            org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager. Otherwise we get an error 
            A probable bug. This is still under investigation-->
    <security:authentication-manager/>
</beans>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

     <security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
     For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.krams.commerce" />

    <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
    Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

</beans>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.krams.tutorial</groupId>
  <artifactId>commerce</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>commerce</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>commerce</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

**The error in tomcat is catalina.out is:**

```
Aug 6, 2013 5:00:41 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/commerce/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
[ERROR] [http-bio-80-exec-382 05:00:41] (ContextLoader.java:initWebApplicationContext:220) Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 16 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 65; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'security:global-method-security'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:714)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:219)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 16; columnNumber: 65; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'security:global-method-security'.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErro
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportS
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleS
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyEl
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scan
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(X
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImp
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(X
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(X
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Doc
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocum
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadB
        ... 43 more
Aug 6, 2013 5:00:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Aug 6, 2013 5:00:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/commerce] startup failed due to previous errors
```

**Thanks you in advance**

Comment: You have to be more specific about the error. Is there any stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry but that's all tomcat says when i try start the application. Just to clarify the applications stops and does even start in tomcat as soon as i add global-method-security

Comment: If logging is enabled thr must be some exception in server logs ?

Comment: I have added the tomcat error log from cataliba.out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put `<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>` this into spring-security and there was a dependency missing. Once I added that it worked just fine.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
<artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to add security to schemaLocation on applicationContext.xml. Something like this:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
```

Then I think it can read your xml right.

**EDIT**: In your case, I think you can use the same schemaLocation from spring-security.xml

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd"
```